# Javascript callback after Tag has been created

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress plugin that allow user to select a photo attached with the Tag.
I used the post_tag_add_form_fields action hook to create the button to choose attached photo then used the created_post_tag action hook to save the attached photo in the database.

In wordpress, Tags will be created using Ajax, I could not get the Ajax response after the Tag was created successfully to remove the selected photo on the form.

Can anyone please help me how to register a javascript callback when the Tag was successfully created in Wordpress.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I found the solution myself. Using jQuery's ajaxComplete function to setup a callback and then check the action of the ajax request like this:

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. Using jQuery's ajaxComplete function to setup a callback and then check the action of the ajax request like this:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, options) {
    if (xhr && xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200
        && options.data && options.data.indexOf('action=add-tag') >= 0) {

        var res = wpAjax.parseAjaxResponse(xhr.responseXML, 'ajax-response');
        if (!res || res.errors) {
            return;
        }
        //Your javascript callback here
    }
});
```

Hope this help.